# JQuery same .toggleClass for many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a big alphabetical list with pagination, which you can see in the pic. My problem is that I want to change css of the Links when a letter is in vision. For example, in the picture, the list is at "C" so that link is bigger than the others. The code I have made this is

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$('#left > p > a[href="#indexc"]').toggleClass('active',
((scroll >= $('#right > #log > table > tbody > tr > td > a[name="indexc"] ').offset().top)
&&(scroll < $('#right > #log > table > tbody > tr > td > a[name="indexd"] ').offset().top))
);
```

So how can I make this for every Letter?

[image: This is my pic]

Comment: The jQuery selector can select many elements, modify it to get the elements you want.

Comment: Your post should include a **[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** - meaning there's a runnable snippet to accurately replicate the issue you're having.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Eury/tsxwyezf/)
I don't know why, but at the fetch it stops

Comment: As @Santi said: a *working* demo is needed. Your link has heaps of code and not much else. That said, there seems to be A) waaaay too much JS (probably) for what you need to do B) Your specificity (eg '#right > #log ... a[name="indexc"]') is (probably) going to get in the way of an elegant solution.